# No php errors in Alpine/Nginx/PHP 7.1.2 with docker

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, docker, alpine

I'm using Alpine / Nginx / PHP-FPM 7.1.2.

I can't get PHP error's to display or output to the `error.log` in my Nginx server block. The `access.log` seems to work just fine.

I've got this at the bottom of `www.conf` in `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/`

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

There is nothing in Docker logs and there are no errors in `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log` either...

What do I need to do display and log errors?

I've also tried the error log as: `/proc/self/fd/2`

Answer (score 1):

I think it was because the error reporting level was not set in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED">>/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

This is producing error's on the screen and in the log.

Hopefully will help somebody..

Comment: And `/proc/self/fd/2` is the correct error log path